# Need to match a certain pattern with regex

Tags: python-2.7

For example: 
@@ Dream is beautiful 1. it. 2. has something bright.
@@ Bird has a nice colors 1. that's. 2. a nice fact.

What I am looking to match is the word between 1. & 2. but I want to set a condition that the line should start with the symbol @@

the regex that works is (?<=1.)[^.]+(?=.), but it does not keep the idea of validating the symbol that is in the beginning of each phrase.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex **@@.*?((?<=1.)[^.]+(?=.))** it's the same of what you wrote but I've added group to identify your select, and I've added non-greedy search for **@@.*** in order to match the symbols @@.

PS: The desired area will be in a group.

Comment: I came up with `(?:@@[^@]*)((?<=1.)[^.]+(?=.))`, and was going to answer but you beat me to it so just gonna post this here for alternative.

Comment: @Confuzing Yes it would do the same exact purpose,thank you